# What are the legal delimiters for Perl 5's pick-your-own-quotes operators?

Tags: perl, quotes

perlop provides various examples of the delimiters you can use for `q`, `qq`, `s`, etc., including `'`, `/`, `#`, and `{` (closing with `}` instead of itself). But what exactly are the rules for what's allowed? I notice that you can't use, for example, whitespace or a letter (edit: a letter is allowed if you put whitespace after the operator name).

Comment: You can also use the same brace/bracket, `q{a}` is the same as `q}a}` (documented somewhere in `perlop`)

Comment: @zdim, They both produce `a`, but `q{...}` is not always the same as `q}...}`. Compare `q{{}}` (produces `{}`) with `q}{}}` (illegal).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We have in [Regex Quote-Like Operators in perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) under `m/PATTERN/msixpodualngc`

> With the `m` you can use any pair of non-whitespace (ASCII) characters as delimiters
>   [...]
>   When using a delimiter character valid in an identifier, whitespace is required after the `m`.

So if you want to use a word character as the delimiter, you'll need to separate it from the operator with whitespace. This applies to both regex and non-regex uses.

```
$ perl -le'print qq afooa'
foo
```

The only one for which you don't need `m` is the solidus (`/`).
The only one for which you don't need `q` is the apostrophe (`'`).
The only one for which you don't need `qq` is the quotation mark (`"`).
The only one for which you don't need `qx` is the grave accent (`` ` ``).

Clearly, quoted characters that are the same as the chosen delimiter must be escaped.

---

A useful read is [Gory details of parsing quoted constructs (perlop)](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Gory-details-of-parsing-quoted-constructs)

A simplified straight rule for general quoting can be found in *Programming Perl*, under *Pick Your Own Quotes* in Chapter 2 *Bits and Pieces* (3rd Ed)

> ... any nonalphanumeric, nonwhitespace delimiter may be used

in reference to the table much like the one [in perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators).

While this comes straight from Camel note that with the use of space between the operator and the string we *can also use alphanumeric delimiters*, as shown in the beginning. And under `use utf8;` [Unicode may be used as well](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunifaq.html#Can-I-use-Unicode-in-my-Perl-sources?), thanks to [ysth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17389/ysth).

Thanks to [ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami) for comments and edit.

---

Since the question is about the exact rules I'd like to note that I couldn't find a single comprehensive statement in the docs. While the first quote here is complete, it refers to *Regex* uses.  The preceding section in `perlop` on general *Quote-Like* operators does not specify the delimiters (while the same rule does apply).

Comment: The second quote is wrong. You can have alphanumeric delimiters, as shown in the first half of your answer.

Comment: @ikegami  Thank you ... i am thinking about augmenting it ... it is a literal quote from Camel ... added a note.  It's tricky, docs aren't necessarily comprehensive on this.

Comment: non-ascii characters can be used too (at least under `use utf8;`)

Comment: @ysth: But with `s///` before 5.20, you need to use `s◆pattern◆◆replacement◆`.

Comment: However you can't use paired Unicode brackets: `q«foo»` gives an error with or without `use utf8;`. Reasonable, but still a bummer.