# What matches this regex in perl: qr!$line!;

Tags: regex, perl

In one source code I found this regex:

```
my $var = qr!$my_string!;
```

I simply can't figure out what this matches. I also searched online, the explanation to qr is quite simple.

Can someone explain it in an human language, please? :)

Comment: This doesn't even seem to be a valid regex. It has $ character in middle of string and not even escaped so this string when used as regex will give errors.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi : as a line of code from Perl, it makes sense :  the `$my_string` will be expanded first, and then that value will be the pattern for the regex matching

Comment: @landru27: Ahh ok, you got a point. I am a noob in perl so oversaw that. Thank for pointing it out.

Comment: Re "*I simply can't figure out what this matches.*", Nothing. That code doesn't perform any matching.

Answer (score 8):

Most [quote-like operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.14.0/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators) can take nearly anything for delimiters.<sup>†</sup> The [qr](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) is no exception, here using `!` as delimiter. It also evaluates ("interpolates") variables that are quoted. So that line of code builds a regex pattern using what is in `$my_string` variable. This pattern is presumably used later in code in regex expressions.  This is normal use.

A complete example:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my $str = q(hey); 

my $re = qr!$str!; 

my $tgt = q(A_hey_C); 

$tgt =~ s/$re/B/; 

say $tgt;  #-->  A_B_C
```

The purpose of `qr` is specifically to construct a regex pattern so one would expect that the `$str` above (`$my_string` in the question), or the pattern in `qr`, would contain regex-specific patterns, perhaps along with other variables assembled in the program. The `$str` above with just a plain string can nicely be used directly in a regex, so this isn't a realistic example.

---

<sup>†</sup> See
   [What are the legal delimiters for Perl 5's pick-your-own-quotes operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43617820/what-are-the-legal-delimiters-for-perl-5s-pick-your-own-quotes-operators/43617962#43617962)

Comment: Thanks for your great explanation. I was not able to find good explanation about the combined usage of "!" and "qr". Any good reference about this kind of combined usage in perl? Thanks.

Comment: @RenChen  I doubt there's anything specific, since `!` is used merely as a delimiter (a character that marks where the quotation starts and stops).  One can say `qr/.../` or `qr(...)` or `qr{...}` or `qr!...!` ... That quotes the string inside under slightly special rules (in comparison with `""`,  which is `qq(...)`) for regex. It also allows regex _modifiers_ (like `my $re = qr/.../i;` for example).  Such a properly quoted and set up "regex pattern" is saved into a variable which is then ready to be used in a regex.

Comment: @RenChen Revisited this accidentally and recalled a post may be useful, added a link